# mySQL - Delete rows in table with Inner Join

Tags: mysql

I've searched but found no solutions that work in my instance.

mySQL db with 2 tables.  using results from table b to identify rows in table a to be deleted.

When I run this query it returns results from table a.

```
SELECT a.* FROM forteweb_vhatest.siteind_frm_item_metas a
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT item_id FROM forteweb_vhatest.siteind_frm_item_metas 
            WHERE field_id = 122
            AND   ExpiryDate < now()
            )b ON a.item_id =  b.item_id ;
```

I get an error when I try to delete these records with

```
DELETE a.* FROM forteweb_vhatest.siteind_frm_item_metas a
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT item_id FROM forteweb_vhatest.siteind_frm_item_metas 
            WHERE field_id = 122
            AND   ExpiryDate < now()
            )b ON a.item_id =  b.item_id ;
```

Can you tell me why?

Thank you.

Comment: 1. Remove '.*' .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.* FROM forteweb_vhatest.siteind_frm_item_metas a
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT item_id FROM forteweb_vhatest.siteind_frm_item_metas 
        WHERE field_id = 122
        AND   ExpiryDate < now()
        )b ON a.item_id =  b.item_id ;
```

/* Added table alias after DELETE */

```
DELETE a FROM forteweb_vhatest.siteind_frm_item_metas a
    INNER JOIN (
            SELECT item_id FROM forteweb_vhatest.siteind_frm_item_metas 
            WHERE field_id = 122
            AND   ExpiryDate < now()
            )b ON a.item_id =  b.item_id ;
```

Comment: Hi Ravi. That looks correct but throws an error in MySQL Workbench.  `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a INNER JOIN (         SELECT item_id FROM forteweb_vhatest.siteind_frm_item_met' at line 1
`                          But may I say the SELECT statement works fine.

Comment: I just copied your select query.  As i can see you are using aliasing "b" for second table but you didn't used the table name in the query.

Comment: Thanks Ravi, it is working now.  Next thing is for me to schedule this with CRON.  Onwards we go!  :)  Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

You should remove `a.*` from the `delete` statement because `delete` does not accept arguments after the `delete` keyword.

It deletes everything that is returned from the query given after the table name. If nothing is given after table name, then all the records will be deleted.

You can check the syntax of `delete` statement [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-delete-query.htm).

Hope this clarifies your doubt:)

Comment: Delete accepts arguments after the keyword; just not *that* argument

Comment: Oh..yeah. just read it online from [this site](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/delete.php) but according to this it only accepts 3 arguments. And in code query, what are you expecting in `a.*`?

Comment: Maybe there is something else going on here.  Even this simple command fails.   `DELETE FROM forteweb_vhatest.siteind_frm_item_metas a
WHERE  a.item_id = 28161;`    I have checked privileges for this user in cPanel and they have ALL PRIVILEGES.

Comment: I did manage to get this to work.  It seems that mySQL doesn't like table alias on a DELETE command.  `DELETE FROM forteweb_vhatest.siteind_frm_item_metas 
WHERE  item_id = 28161;`.  But my problem still is occurring on my original query.  I will continue to experiment.

Comment: Changing my script to this as a test worked.  `DELETE FROM forteweb_vhatest.siteind_frm_item_metas 
WHERE  item_id IN (28211,28239);`   But when I add script to bring back the item_id inside the IN brackets it fails even though the select statement works on its own.  `DELETE FROM forteweb_vhatest.siteind_frm_item_metas 
WHERE  item_id IN (
   SELECT item_id FROM forteweb_vhatest.siteind_frm_item_metas 
   WHERE field_id = 122
   AND   ExpiryDate < now()
   );`.